# What kind of redirect is in use here? And is it unhealthy for the new site?

Tags: redirect, seo

I was asked to make a website for a restaurant that recently changed owners. They wanted a new URL. The owner of the old site enacted a redirect to the new site.

Old site: http://www.refugelounge.com

New site: http://www.therefugeyc.com

I don't know a lot about redirects but I have a sneaking suspicion that whatever it is going on here is hurting the new site's pagerank and traffic. The old URL comes up first in Google and shows up as an exact clone of the new site. And when visiting the old site, the URL remains static no matter what page is visited.

What's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's bad.

They use frames (`frameset` + `frame`). Despite being [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) ("*must* not be used by authors"), frames are bad for usability (it's not possible for users to link to a specific page).

They should use a [HTTP 301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirect.